# Codes P0320 and P1391

Tags: dodge, misfire, ram

My 1998 Dodge Laramie pickup truck with the 360 motor, automatic transmission and rear wheel drive has been pulling the same 2 codes up, even after replacing new computer and a new distributer (only replaced cap rotor,and cam sensor,and,5 new crank sensors).

When the symptoms started it would do it every couple of months, then persisted to daily.  Now I can't even drive it.  It misfires, smokes and runs terribly. On some days it would just go away.  If I sit there, revving the motor for a while, it would clear it up but doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the cam position sensor and you are still getting the code for it, chances are the sensor wasn't the cause. Check the electrical connection to it using a multimeter:

- make sure the sensor is getting power from it
- make sure the PCM is getting a signal from it

Move the electrical connector around while you are testing, see if you can make it lose continuity.